# Issues with setting configurations in Memgraph Docker compose

Tags: docker, memgraphdb, memgraph

I'm setting up a Memgraph Platform instance using Docker Compose. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
 version: "3"
services:
  memgraph-platform:
    image: "memgraph/memgraph-platform"
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "3000:3000"
      - "7444:7444"
    volumes:
      - mg2_lib:/var/lib/memgraph
      - mg2_log:/var/log/memgraph
      - mg2_etc:/etc/memgraph

    environment:
      - MEMGRAPH="--bolt-session-inactivity-timeout=9000  --query-execution-timeout-sec=1000  --log-level=TRACE"

    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
    
volumes:
  mg2_lib:
  mg2_log:
  mg2_etc:
```

After running the instance and executing `SHOW CONFIG;` in Memgraph Lab, I noticed that the `--query-execution-timeout-sec` and `--log-level` settings are not being applied, but the -`-bolt-session-inactivity-timeout` is set correctly.

Comment: it seeams your environment configurations have two space at --query-execution-.. how about try this environment? - MEMGRAPH="--bolt-session-inactivity-timeout=9000 --query-execution-timeout-sec=1000 --log-level=TRACE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there were some issues while setting the environment variables in Docker. Docker tends to ignore all but the first flag. What seems to work is if you create a new `.env` file and list your config flags there. Could you try setting your `docker-compose` file this way:

```
version: "3"
services:
  memgraph-platform:
    image: "memgraph/memgraph-platform"
    ports:
      - "7687:7687"
      - "3000:3000"
      - "7444:7444"
    volumes:
      - mg2_lib:/var/lib/memgraph
      - mg2_log:/var/log/memgraph
      - mg2_etc:/etc/memgraph

    env_file:
      - /.env 

    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
    
volumes:
  mg2_lib:
  mg2_log:
  mg2_etc:
```

and in your `.env` file add config flags you've set:

```
MEMGRAPH="--bolt-session-inactivity-timeout=9000  --query-execution-timeout-sec=1000  --log-level=TRACE"
```